# Webpage >> Frame >> popup window handling

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this webpage which I am trying to automate. here are the steps and functioning of application.

1. Launch Application using Selenium
2. On clicking certain button a frame would pop up over the main web page
3. I able to perform operations on frame thru selenium web driver
4. but there is a calendar icon in the same frame.
5. once you click on calendar icon a pop up window with calendar and Ok button pops up.
6. I able to select date in pop up and as soon as i click on OK button the pop up window closes itself automatically.
7. Now i want to switch to FRame again as to perform further operations. but i m not able to do so.
8. My script crashes with the error "Window not found. The browser window may have been closed."

below is part of my code

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='VDC_VM_ScheduledTask.RequestedDateTime.ControlImage']")).click();
// clicking on calendar icon
Set afterPopup = Driver.getWindowHandles();
System.out.println(afterPopup);
afterPopup.removeAll(beforePopup);
System.out.println(afterPopup.size());
if(afterPopup.size() == 1) {
    Driver.switchTo().window((String)afterPopup.toArray()[0]);
    Driver.findElement(By.id("submitButton")).click();
   //    Switching windows and clicking Ok in calendar pop up window which closes it automatically
}
Driver.switchTo().frame(0);
// this step fails
```

Comment: The last step must be failing because after closing the calendar popup the control must be returning to the frame only rather than the main window.

Comment: But even if I comment the line Driver.switchTo().frame(0); then also the script crashes.

Comment: Is there any further step which makes the script to crash?

Comment: if(afterPopup.size() == 1) {
                        Driver.switchTo().window((String)afterPopup.toArray()[0]);
                        Driver.findElement(By.id("submitButton")).click();
    //    Switching windows and clicking Ok in calendar pop up window which closes it automatically
                    }

                    Driver.switchTo().frame(0);

Comment: Driver.findElement(By.name("submitorderform")).click(); - this is the next step which I am trying to perform present in the frame

Comment: Could you post the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
        String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        Set<String> windows= driver.getWindowHandles();
        if (windows.size() > 1) {
            //first remove main window
            windows.remove(mainWindow);
            //switching to new/child window and perform some action on new window if required. Then close it.
            driver.switchTo().window(windows.iterator().next());
            driver.close();
            //switching back to mainWindow, Then continue with your actions.
            driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);
            windows.clear();
        }
```