# selenium and popup interactions

Tags: selenium, popup, webdriver

Hi I have a problem with finding elements by webdriver as soon as I start 
interacting with a popup, 

the first and second sout where I get the title and url works which means that my driver is on the right window but as soon as I try to locate any element the console tells me sorry no element found and I tried locating it by xpath or by css or just by id="xxxxx"

```
    hiLoginPage.setUsername("me");
    hiLoginPage.setPassword("pass");
    hiLoginPage.clickLogin();

    driver.close();
    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        <br>driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    hiHomePage = new HiHomePage(driver);
    System.out.print(driver.getTitle());
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"xxxxx\"]")).sendKeys("woj);
```

Comment: which URL are you using..??

Comment: System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
gives me the popup url

Comment: Which I want to interact with

Comment: Can you post your xpath..So that i can is that right xpath or not.

Comment: and the line "driver.manage().window().maximize();" maximizes the popup window but that as far as it goes

Comment: By.xpath("//*[@id=\"form1:custIDValue\"]")

Comment: May be you are findly this element on pop up window.?? Once will you post your web site URL.???

Comment: as far as I would love to send a link to that web site buts it's a internal web based application then, I cannot sorry

Comment: atleast post your  html code. And once check how many windows are opened using, driver.getWindowHandles().size();. Here if the size is 1, then that is fine.

Comment: I just did sout on the size and its one

Comment: Ok that is fine. post your html code or you can find your xpath using firePath. firePath is an easy way to find element's xpath.

Comment: if the driver would not be on the right page it would not give me the right page title and url which does, thats way I'm just stack and I really dont have a clue how to go forward with that

Comment: I'm finding the element xpath by using copy xpath in chrome when I inspect the element then the xpath or css its the right one

Comment: hiLoginPage.setUsername("me");
    hiLoginPage.setPassword("pass");
    hiLoginPage.clickLogin();

Comment: it works on the Login page but as soon as I click Login button and it opens a new window hiHomePage

Comment: once try to give implicit Wait. Some times it will give element not found exception.

Comment: just to be even safe I put Thread.sleep(3000); but with no luck

Comment: Have you used implicitWait().?? And When did you get that element not found exception? after clicking on submit button or before submit??

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"xxxxx\"]")).sendKeys("woj);

Comment: Thats when I get element not found, and just to point the popup window is open

Comment: the test runs and open the login page puts the credentials clicks login and the new popup window comes up and on that new window I'n not able to locate any element apart from getting its url and title

Comment: Hey are you trying find element on newly opened window or main window??

Comment: on newly open window thats way I have     for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        <br>driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }

Comment: to get hold of the new window

Comment: System.out.print(driver.getTitle());
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
I get the new window title and URL

Comment: once check your xpath. i think that may be the problem, i am not sure about it b'coz you did not post your Html code.

Comment: the xpath to the element is right, I'm using "copy xpath" from the element inspector, but maybe this is worth mentioning the new window is not open as a tab it's a popup window

Comment: getWindowHandle() will give you the mainWindow. If you want to switch to new Window, just close the mainWindow and switch to new Window. Once refer this: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790534/webpage-frame-popup-window-handling/30796544#30796544**

Comment: driver.close();
    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        <br>driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
by doing this I'm already switching to a new popup window

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve it. Since the structure of the html was as follow:

```
<html>
 <head>...</head>
 <frameset>...</frameset>
 </html>
```

and the only reason that I was getting the correct title on syso(title), my driver was on the right window but to access elements on that window it required a switch to a new frame:

driver.switchTo().frame("main_frame");