# How to handle nested popup windows in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Below is my code to switch to first popup window:

```
String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); 

String subWindowHandler = null;

Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 

Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {

subWindowHandler = iterator.next();

 }

driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);

driver.findelement(By.xpath("<xpath of the element>")).click();
```

Below is the code for getting inside another popup window which is also inside the window i just opened above, which comes after i click on the element ---->

```
parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle();

subWindowHandler = null;

handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 

iterator = handles.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {

subWindowHandler = iterator.next();

 }

driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("<xpath of the element>")).click();

driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);

driver.findelement(By.xpath("<xpath of element>").click();

driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);
```

Everytime, i run this code, it runs properly for first set of code, i.e. it will enter inside the window and when it comes to run the second i.e. the inner popup window, what it does is, will open the inner window but then fail to click on the element and always throws me an error as below:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element
```

The elements are not part of an iframe as well to switch to it. I have tried a lot ways to do it using xpath, have used complete xpath given by browser and also using my own xpath written which also gives the same result, but still throws an error.

Please advise on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once refer this link: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790534/webpage-frame-popup-window-handling/30796544#30796544**. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @Adarsh Kumar - In first part of code BEFORE getting handles on driver, you are not performing any action(clicking on any link, button, etc.) to open/generate new windows. Then in this case you will always get parent window handle only in Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();. So your not achieving anything by switching windows as it will point to same parent window. PLEASE revisit your code and verify. Try printing window handles to verify.